# cant add image in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to create a product page by using php but the product image is cant get. I do this in database plus php. Please some one help me, I dont know the method the coding I used is rigth or wrong. This is a ecommerce website project

```
       <body>
<div align="center">
        <h1 align="center">Organic Jus</h1>
        <?php
        include("conn.php");
        $result=mysql_query("select * from organic") OR DIE(mysql_error());;
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        if(@$connt % 2==0){
        ?>

        <table border="0" cellpadding="2px" width="1000px">
        <?php } ?>
        <td width="500"><img src="image/AlmondLove.jpg<?=$row['pic']?>"/>
        <br><b><?=$row['productname']?></b><br/>
        <?=$row['details']?><br/>
        Price:<big style="color:green">$<?=$row['price']?></big><br/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Add to Cart"
        onclick="addtocart(<?=$row['product_id']?>)"/>
        </form>
        </td>

        <?php
        @$count++;
        }?>
        </table>
        </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: what have you get in `src` attribute?
have get prodeuct name under image?

Comment: Impossible to understand. Please concentrate on you English and at least read what you have written because this type of content is just disrespectful towards people reading it.

Comment: It's a new or legacy project?

Comment: First of all, stop using mysql functions. They're deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead. Second: You're incrementing `@$count++` at the end, but in your if statement you check fof `@$connt` - misspelling. This should be `count` too  think.

Comment: after i correct the coding also its showing errors      Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ep\catalog.php on line 6

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ep\catalog.php on line 6

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
<html>

<head>
  <style>
     tr.d0 td {
         background-color: #F8F8F9;
         border-bottom-style: solid;
         border-bottom-width: 1px;
         border-color: #C5D0D9;
     }
     tr.d1 td {
         background-color: #FFF5EC;
         border-bottom-style: solid;
         border-bottom-width: 1px;
         border-color: #C5D0D9;
     }  
  </style>
</head>

  <body>
      <div align="center">
        <h1 align="center">Organic Jus</h1>
        <?php
           include("conn.php");
           $result=mysql_query("select * from organic") OR DIE(mysql_error());;
           $connt=0;
           ?>
              <table border="0" cellpadding="2px" width="1000px">
           <?
           while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
             if($connt % 2==0){
                $cls='d0';
             }else{
                $cls='d1';
             } 
        ?> 

                 <td class="<?=$cls?>" width="500">
                   <td>   
                      <img src="image/<?=$row['pic']?>" border="0"> <!-- path to image dir + image name from db -->
                      <br/>
                      <b><?=$row['productname']?></b>
                      <br/>
                      <?=$row['details']?>
                      <br/>
                      Price:<big style="color:green">$<?=$row['price']?></big>
                      <br/>
                      <br/>
                      <input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(<?=$row['product_id']?>)"/>
                   </td>
                 </tr>

        <?php
                $count++;
        }?>
               </table>
      </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ep\catalog.php on line 53

Comment: what do you have on line 53 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ep\catalog.php ?